# Incorrect register using mingw64

Tags: mingw-w64

I'm trying to use sezero's mingw64 to compile a project I found online, but I keep running into the following problems

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\LocalTemp\ccPmAPBy.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\Me\AppData\LocalTemp\ccPmAPBy.s:1668: Error: incorrect register `%edx' used with `q' suffix
logreg.cpp: In function 'double logreg_cdn_Ldiff(double, int, double)':
logreg.cpp:103:18: error: 'isnan' was not declared in this scope
mm_lasso.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
mm_lasso.cpp:53:60: error: 'getopt' was not declared in this scope
mm_lasso.cpp:57:31: error: 'optarg' was not declared in this scope
```

The command I'm running is:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -pthread -fopenmp lasso.cpp logreg.cpp read_matrix_market.cpp mmio.c mm_lasso.cpp write_matrix_market.cpp shared.cpp -o mm_lasso -lgomp -O3
```

I was wondering if anyone had this problem before and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know that in rubenvb's mingw64, they made a change to the isnan function in trunk\mingw-w64-headers\crt\math.h (see http://mingw-w64.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mingw-w64/trunk/mingw-w64-headers/crt/math.h?r1=3066&r2=5518), apparently specifically to handle x64 issues.